# What verbs can you use in a sentence "The movie "Boyhood" runs for three hours"?

Tags: cinema

What verbs can you use to express the duration of a movie other than "run"?

Example sentence:

*Boyhood* runs for three hours.

Comment: It *lasts* three hours.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't want to use "runs for," or are you just curious about other options? "Goes on" is another option; it can carry a connotation that the duration is too long. Example sentence: "But the greatest trouble with *The Longest Day* is a very simple one: it **goes on** for three hours."  – [*Interviews with Dwight Macdonald*](https://books.google.com/books?id=pgeG-OhdE5sC&pg=PA16&dq=%22goes+on+for+three+hours%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjmnd7nq8DKAhUJ6GMKHccGDc84ChDoAQgfMAE#v=onepage&q=%22goes%20on%20for%20three%20hours%22&f=false), edited by Michael Wreszin

Comment: Thank you. I'm just curious because I used to know many verbs and now I can remember only one of them.

Comment: *Boyhood* drags on for three hours.  *Boyhood* zips by in three hours.

Comment: "Boyhood" takes 3 hours (to watch)... or "Manhood" begins 3 hours after "Boyhood".

Comment: I've seen that movie. I'd say *drags on for 3 hours* is more like it. I felt like I'd missed 3 days of work by the time it was over.

Comment: *Boyhood* ***lasted*** for longer than I could stay awake for.  I plan on trying again ...

Comment: *Boyhood* is three hours long.

Comment: One could always say "plods on for three hours" or "bumbles along for three hours".

Comment: If the movie is particularly uninteresting, critics and fans would usually comment that the movie "stretched" for 3 hours! But this movie has a 100% approval rating on Metacritic (WOW!). So it boils down to your opinion on the movie.

Comment: "Boyhood" clocks in at three hours. Don

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first micro-question to consider is "Why is *'runs'* common?"

Movies seem to have inherited this term from theater where "limited runs", "re-runs", "plays that ran for a season", and "a play that ran for 3 hours" are all common terms.

The verb usage of *runs* with movies is just as ambiguous about whether it is the "length of time it was available in theaters" or "the length of a single showing".

Noun usage is much clearer. "That movie had a run..." speaks of availability. "That movie had a runtime..." speaks of individual length.

**Micro-question 2:** "What other verbs can be used, that do not express a qualitative opinion?"
Almost any "presentational action" verb can be used:

- Shows, plays, lasts
- Situational: projects, displays, performs, *-casts

**Micro-question 3:** "What other verbs can be used, that **do** express a qualitative opinion?"
Many "Adjectival verbs" can work

- positive: captivates, thrills, zips
- negative: drags, chugs, plods

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above, "goes for" is particularly common, at least in Australia English.  Here's a random review from this link http://www.abc.net.au/rollercoaster/therap/reviews/s756056.htm

> Hey people! I urge you people to go and see this movie. It is a great
>   film and has a good storyline (for you people who find it hard to
>   follow one) **The movie goes for about 1.5 hours** (for those of you with
>   short attention spans) but in that time there is action and
>   excitement.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+movie+lasts%2C+the+movie+runs%2C+the+movie+goes+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20movie%20lasts%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20movie%20runs%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 0):

H R Rambler: Micro question 1. The reason for a movie 'running' for its duration is that the physical film (before we got digital files and DVDs) always 'ran' through the projector. The same usage of 'to run' applies to thread leaving a bobbin, grain leaving a hopper and so on. This is a different use of 'to run' from the theatrical term which refers to the length of time the play is on at a given theatre. I don't believe that lantern slide presentations where a series of separate glass slides were shown were said to 'run', I think that they 'lasted'.